# How can I use GetNotifications into AlarmReceiver.java?

Tags: java, android

I have a small problem with a code in java / android.

Currently using this code in MainActivity:

```
private class GetNotifications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(ApiJsonNotificationsURL);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray notifications = jsonObj.getJSONArray("notifications");
                for (int i = 0; i < notifications.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject n = notifications.getJSONObject(i);

                    int id = (i);
                    String title = n.getString("title");
                    String message = n.getString("message");
                    String image = n.getString("image");


                    //notification
                    MyNotificationManager mNotificationManager = new MyNotificationManager(getApplicationContext());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    if(image.equals("null")){
                        mNotificationManager.showSmallNotification(id, title, message, intent);
                    }else{
                        mNotificationManager.showBigNotification(id, title, message, image, intent);
                    }
                    //notification


                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                /*runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });*/
            }
        } else {
            /*runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });*/

        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

and I call him onCreate this way:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new GetNotifications().execute();
}
```

How do I use new GetNotifications().execute() in AlarmReceiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "here i want use GetNotifications", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    }    
}
```

I'm a beginner with JAVA and I do not know how to do it.
I've been trying to do this for a few days.
It returns error to "context".
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same `AsyncTask` in `AlarmReceiver` also like

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "here i want use GetNotifications", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new GetNotifications(context).execute();

    }



    private class GetNotifications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private Context context;
        public GetNotifications(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

and use `Context` from `onReceive` method.